# C++ biwise operator Or two variable

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I want to split an int variable into four char variables, then merge it into an int variable.
But the result was not as expected.

```
int a = 123546;        //0x1e29a
char b[4]{ 0 };
b[0] = a;              //0x9a
b[1] = a >> 8;         //0xe2
b[2] = a >> 16;        //0x01
b[3] = a >> 24;        //0x0

int c = 0;

c = b[3];              //0x0
c = ((c << 8) | b[2]); //0x01
c = ((c << 8) | b[1]); //0xffffffe2 -> What is it??
c = ((c << 8) | b[0]); //0xffffff9a
```

Please help me!

Comment: The result is as expected, but your int c does not ensure fitting 4 bytes. Check your architecture for int size.

Comment: Apparently your `char` is signed, so it gets sign-extended when converted to `int`.

Answer (score -1):

you have several options (remember int is not unsigned int and I think you mean 32 bit uint so I will use another type)

1.

```
union
{
  uint32_t value;
  uint8_t bytes[4];
}myunion;

myunion.value = 0x11223344;
and check muunion.bytes[xx] :)
```

Another solution

```
void ToBytes(uint32_t value, uint8_t *bytes)
{
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
   byte[i] = value & 0xff;
   value >> = 8;
 }
}
```

or

```
uint32_t value;
uint8_t *bytes = &value;
```